# how to display thumbnail of all file and folder using dropbox api?

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am working on one application in which i have to download image and video file from Dropbox. So i use dropbox sdk 1.6.3 for android. but how to display thumbnail of image and video file for user to watch and download particular image and video from Dropbox? And what if user want to download multiple file at time? How to code it?

Comment: You may just be looking for the [`getThumbnail`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getThumbnail(java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.ThumbSize,%20com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.ThumbFormat,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) and [`getFile`](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.html#getFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream,%20com.dropbox.client2.ProgressListener)) methods?

Comment: @Greg thank you, you really give perfect answer.